# Refactor related conditionals without combining

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, conditional-statements, pixel

I have a pixel/location, we'll call it 4,4 on a graph.
I'm attempting to refactor a function that checks to see if pixels around it, meet a certain criteria, in all 8 directions (diagonally, horizontally, and vertically), and if it meets that criteria, take a common action, that has a return value.

For instance:

```
int weight=0;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(4,4)) == true)
    weight +=100;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(4,5)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(4,3)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(5,5)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(3,3)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(3,4)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(5,4)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(5,3)) == true)
    weight +=10;
if (CheckWeight(new Point(3,5)) == true)
    weight +=10;
```

Is there a good way to refactor these, so if I have to change certain things here, such as function I'm calling to check the weight, or condition I'm checking against, or weight increment, that I'm not duplicating my efforts 8 times?

I've had other programmers I know already suggest to just **combine** them under one check, which I obviously can't do, cause it might meet 3 of these checks, and give me a weight of 30 this time, and 5 of these checks and give me a weight of 50 next time.

**Edit:** This routine will be run on 1920x1080 pixel maps, so several million times; performance could be a real issue involved in the refactoring.

Comment: was the first `+=100` intentionally or just a typo?

Comment: First one is intentional, I'm basically looking for an 40 weight, if the first pixel (the actual pixel) meets my condition, so either the pixel I'm checking, or more than half the surrounding pixels, needs to meet the condition I'm checking.

Comment: The "== true" part is superfluous. CheckWeight already returns a `boolean` and this is what the if-statement needs. If `CheckWeight` returns `true` you basically get `true==true --> true`. If not, you get `false==true --> false`. It is like multiplying a number by 1. It does not change anything.

Comment: true, was focused more on the conditionals, I totally overlooked that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach would be to refactor the common code to a for loop that would iterate through all points near the target one. Sample code follows:

```
var target = new Point(4, 4);

int weight = 0;
if (CheckWeight(target) == true)
    weight += 100;

var points = GetNearestPointsFrom(target);

foreach (var p in points)
{
    if (CheckWeight(p) == true)
        weight += 10;
}
```

You would need to implement the `GetNearestPointsFrom` method to return the correct points. By going this way you're also encapsulating the logic for asserting the nearest points in a separate method, which I find more maintainable.

---

*Update*:
Taking in consideration that you're limited by performance constraints and you mention that you may need to change the `CheckWeight` by another function, I would verify if wrapping the `if` checks in a method that accepts a `Predicate<Point>` and a weight increment value would not affect performance too much. This way changing the `CheckWeight` method or the increment is performed only once. Sample code:

```
private static void GetWeight(Predicate<Point> predicate, int weightIncrement)
{
    int weight = 0;
    if (predicate(new Point(4, 4)) == true)
        weight += 100;
    if (predicate(new Point(4, 5)) == true)
        weight += weightIncrement;
    // ... Remaining checks ...
}
```

Comment: Faster than Dasblin's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8347171/758118) but it's still magnitudes slower averaging between 18 to 23 seconds.

Comment: @Brian Deragon, check my comment in the other answer. No one knew of the performance requirements, so most people will answer according to what they know only.

Comment: nice, I like the use of the predicate, that helps a lot; didn't think of that, and it didn't really slow it down, 3 to 5 seconds per run, a bit slower, but I can deal with that, easy price to pay for the maintenance nightmare being gone.

Answer (score 3):

```
int weight = 0;
for (int dx = -1 ; dx <= 1 ; dx++) {
    for (int dy = -1 ; dy <= 1 ; dy++) {
        if (CheckWeight(new Point(4+dx, 4+dy))) {
            weight += (dx==0 && dy == 0) ? 100 : 10;
        }
     }
}
```

To speed things up a bit, you can unroll one loop using a cute little trick:

```
// Declare this in your class
static readonly int[] dd = new int{1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,0,1,1};

// Use this code to calculate the weight
int weight = CheckWeight(new Point(4, 4)) ? 100 : 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    if (CheckWeight(new Point(4+dd[i], 4+dd[i+1]))) {
        weight += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: while that works...it runs **a lot** slower when I check 2.5 million pixels (before it checked them in about 2 seconds, using this method, it takes between 71 and 73 seconds)

Comment: @BrianDeragon I see! That must have been the reason why your original code [unrolled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) these loops in the first place.

Comment: @Brian Deragon, you hid that requirement from the question, which will probably invalidate most of the answers that did not know you had performance requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that was an issue myself...until we're checking several million pixels 1000x1000, or 1920x1080

Comment: @BrianDeragon I updated the answer with something that may be a bit more performant. It's not going to be close to your 2.5 seconds, but it's probably going to be a lot faster than 73 seconds, too.

Comment: It is hard to believe that the loops are slowing down the process so much. May be it has to do with the number of commands and data the first level cache can hold. It is hard to say. Try passing the coordinates to CheckWeight as 2 int parameters in order to save the time needed to create the Point structure. Try using a 3 x 3 weight matrix (filter matrix) in order to get rid of the check for the central point. Try making just one loop and unroll the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

What about for-loops?

```
int x = 4;
int y = 4;
int weight = 0; 
for (int dx = -1; dx <= +1; dx++) {
    for (int dy = -1; dy <= +1; dy++) {
        if (CheckWeight(new Point(x+dx, y+dy)))
            weight += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: By reviewing your example, I saw that the central point has a +100, not +10. But you can easily correct that. You could also use a 3 x 3 weight matrix (or should I call it filter matrix). This would be a more universal and more flexible approach.

Comment: while that works (I had to readd my check for +100, its too slow, see dasblins answer, also, code gets a little messy, cause of the center pixel having a different weight.

Comment: When using loops, CheckWeight is called at one place only. You could to what CheckWeight does directly inside of the loops.

Comment: if performance is an issue, maybe you can avoid creating a Point in every loop and instead calling CheckWeight(x,y)